Periodic perturbation of ODE
Recently, I have read Khasminskii's book (Stochastic Stability of Differential Equations). In Section 3.5, the author mentioned that the following is well-known in the theory of ODEs.

If $x_0$ is an asymptotically stable equilibrium point of an autonomous system $\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}t=F(x)$ and $f(t)$ is $\theta$-periodic, then for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ the system $\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}t=F(x)+\epsilon f(t)$ has a $\theta$-periodic solution in a neighborhood of the equilibrium point.

But I didn't find references about the fact. Could you give me some references or hints? Thanks!

Actually, there is a much more general result.
Assume that $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and
$G : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ are smooth vector valued functions with $G$ being $\theta-$periodic, i.e. $G(x, t + \theta) = G(x, t)$  any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Define the system of ODEs
$$\frac{dx}{dt} \,=\, F(x) + \varepsilon \,G(x, t)$$
where $\varepsilon$ is a small parameter. Without loss of generality assume that $F(0) = 0$. Denote by $DF(x)$ the $n \times n$ Jacobian matrix of $F(x)$ and by $DG(x,t)$ the $n \times n$ Jacobian matrix of $G(x, t)$ with respect to the variables $x$ only, while treating $t$ as a fixed variable. Set $DF(0) = A$.
Theorem. If $F(0) = 0$ and all eigenvalues of $A = DF(0)$ have non-zero real parts, then, for all small enough values of $\varepsilon$, there is a periodic solution of the system of ODEs
$$\frac{dx}{dt} \,=\, F(x) + \varepsilon \,G(x, t)$$
Sketch of proof.
Given initial conditions $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\tau \in [0, \theta]$, let
$$x(t) = \phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon)$$ be the unique solution to the initial value problem
\begin{align}
&\frac{dx}{dt} \,=\, F(x) + \varepsilon \,G(x, t)\\
&x(\tau) = x
\end{align}
i.e.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon) \,=\, F\big(\,\phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon)\,\big) + \varepsilon \,G\big(\,\phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon)\,, \,t\,\big)$$
and
$$\phi(\tau, \tau, x, \varepsilon) = x$$
By the theorem on smooth dependence with respsect to parameters and initial conditions, the map
\begin{align}
&\phi \, : \, \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \, \to \, \mathbb{R}^n\\
&\phi \, : \, (t, \tau, x, \varepsilon) \,\mapsto \,  \phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon)
\end{align} exists, at least locally, and is differentiable. Since $x(t) = 0$ is a solution to the system, when $\varepsilon = 0$, then $\phi(t, \tau, 0, 0) = 0$ for all $t$ and $\tau$. Hence, there exist $a>0, \, b>0, $ and an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x=0$, such that for any $(\tau, x) \in (-b, b) \times U$ and for any $\varepsilon \in (-a, a)$ the solution $\phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon)$ of the initial value problem
\begin{align}
&\frac{dx}{dt} \,=\, F(x) + \varepsilon \,G(x, t)\\
&x(\tau) = x
\end{align}
exists for all $t \in (\tau-\delta, \tau+\theta + \delta)$ for some $\delta > 0$.
For a fixed $\tau$, define the map
\begin{align}
&P_{\tau} \, : \, U \times (-a, a) \to 
\mathbb{R}^n\\
&P_{\tau} \,:\, (x, \varepsilon) \,\mapsto\, P_{\tau}(x, \varepsilon) = \phi(\tau + \theta, \tau, x, \varepsilon)
\end{align}
Then assume, that for a fixed $\varepsilon$ and for some $x \in U$, the solution $\phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon)$ is periodic, i.e.
$\phi(t + \theta, \tau, x, \varepsilon) = \phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, for $t=\tau$ we have
$\phi(\tau + \theta, \tau, x, \varepsilon) = \phi(\tau, \tau, x, \varepsilon) = x$, which in the language of the map $P_{\tau}$ yields $P_{\tau}(x, \varepsilon) = x$ is a fixed point. Conversely, if for a fixed $\varepsilon$ and for some $x \in U$, we have $P_{\tau}$ yields $P_{\tau}(x, \varepsilon) = x$ which means $\phi(\tau + \theta, \tau, x, \varepsilon) = \phi(\tau, \tau, x, \varepsilon) = x$. Consider the solutions
$\phi(t + \theta, \tau, x, \varepsilon)$ and $\phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon)$. Then, by the  definition of $\phi$,
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon) \,=\, F\big(\,\phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon)\,\big) + \varepsilon \,G\big(\,\phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon)\,, \,t\,\big)\\
&\phi(\tau, \tau, x, \varepsilon) = x
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(t + \theta, \tau, x, \varepsilon) \,=\, F\big(\,\phi(t+\theta, \tau, x, \varepsilon)\,\big) + \varepsilon \,G\big(\,\phi(t+\theta, \tau, x, \varepsilon)\,, \,t + \theta\,\big) \\
&\phantom{\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(t + \theta, \tau, x, \varepsilon) }\,=\, F\big(\,\phi(t+\theta, \tau, x, \varepsilon)\,\big) + \varepsilon \,G\big(\,\phi(t+\theta, \tau, x, \varepsilon)\,, \,t \big)\\
&\phi(\tau + \theta, \tau, x, \varepsilon) = \phi(\tau, \tau, x, \varepsilon) = x
\end{align}
Thus, we can see that both $\phi(t + \theta, \tau, x, \varepsilon)$ and $\phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon)$ solve the same initial value problem
\begin{align}
&\frac{dx}{dt} \,=\, F(x) + \varepsilon \,G(x, t)\\
&x(\tau) = x
\end{align}
(here the periodicity $G(x, t+\theta) = G(x, t)$ played a crucial role, without it, this statement is generally not true), which by the existence and uniqueness theorem of differentiable systems of ODEs implies that the two solutions coincide, i.e.
$\phi(t + \theta, \tau, x, \varepsilon)\,=\,\phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}.$
The bottom line is that the system has a periodic solution of period $\theta$ if and only if $P_{\tau}$ has a fixed point.
So our goal will be to prove that if $P_{\tau}(0, 0) = 0$ then there exists a continuous family of points $x(\varepsilon)$, for small enough $\varepsilon$ such that
$P_{\tau}\big(x(\varepsilon), \varepsilon\big) = x(\varepsilon)$.
To that end, we will apply the implicit function theorem to the system of equations
$$P_{\tau}(x,\,\varepsilon) - x \,=\, 0$$ Since by assumption $x=0$ is a solution to the system when $\varepsilon =0$, then $$P_{\tau}(0,\,0) - 0 \,=\, 0 - 0 = 0$$ To apply the implicit function theorem, one needs to prove that the matrix of derivatives $$DP_{\tau}(x, \varepsilon)_{|_{(x=0, \varepsilon=0)}} - I$$ with respect to the variables $x$ and evaluated at $x=0, \varepsilon=0$ is an invertиble matrix (matrix with no kernel). Since the map $P$ is directly linked to the solution map $\phi$, the derivatives of $P$ with respect to $x$ are directly linked to the derivatives of $\phi$ with respect to $x$. Differentiating a solution $\phi$ with respect to $x$ is achieved by differentiating the original system of ODEs with respect to $x$, which becomes
\begin{align*}
& \frac{d}{dt} D\phi \,=\, DF\big(\phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon)\big)\,D\phi \,+\, \varepsilon\,DG\big(\phi(t, \tau, x, \varepsilon), t\big)\, D\phi
\end{align*}
We need to set $x=0$ and $\varepsilon=0$, which gives us
\begin{align*}
& \frac{d}{dt} D\phi \,=\, DF\big(\phi(t, \tau, 0, 0)\big)\,D\phi \,+\, 0\,DG\big(\phi(t, \tau, 0, 0), t\big)\, D\phi
\end{align*}
Since by assumption $\phi(t, \tau, 0, 0) = 0$ for all $t$, we arrive at the linear system
\begin{align*}
& \frac{d}{dt} D\phi \,=\, DF(0)\,D\phi
\end{align*} and since we denoted $DF(0)=A$,
\begin{align*}
& \frac{d}{dt} D\phi \,=\, A\,D\phi
\end{align*}
the solution of the latter linear system is $D\phi(t, \tau, 0, 0) \,=\, e^{(t-\tau)A}$ and consequently
$$DP_{\tau}(0, 0) \,=\,D\phi(\tau + \theta, \tau, 0, 0) \,=\, e^{(\tau + \theta -\tau)A} \,=\, e^{\theta A}$$ Let us represent $A = U\,\Lambda\,U^{-1}$ where $\Lambda$ is the Jordan normal form of $A$. Then
$$DP_{\tau}(x, \varepsilon)_{|_{(x=0, \varepsilon=0)}} - I\,=\, e^{\theta A} - I \,=\,
e^{\theta U\,\Lambda\,U^{-1}} - U\,U^{-1} \,=\,
U\,e^{\theta \Lambda}\,U^{-1} - U\,U^{-1} \,=\, U\big(\,e^{\theta \Lambda} - I\,\big)\,U^{-1}$$
Since $\Lambda$ is upper-triangular matrix, so is $e^{\theta\, \Lambda}$. By assumption, the eigenvalues of $A$ are all with non-zero real parts, which means that the same is true for $\Lambda$. Consequently, the eigenvalues, which are the diagonal elements of $e^{\theta\, \Lambda}$, are all with real parts not equal to $1$ and therefore the diagonal elements of $e^{\theta \Lambda} - I$ are all non-zero. Cоnsequently, $e^{\theta\, \Lambda} - I$ is an invertible matrix, which means that $A - I = U\big(\,e^{\theta \Lambda} - I\,\big)\,U^{-1}$ is also invertible matrix, as a product of invertible matrices. Hence,   $DP_{\tau}(x, \varepsilon)_{|_{(x=0, \varepsilon=0)}} - I\,=\, e^{\theta A} - I$ is an invertible matrix, and therefore by the implicit function theorem, there is a small neighbourhood $(-a, a)$ such that for $\varepsilon \in (-a, a)$ there is solution $x(\varepsilon)$ such that
$$P_{\tau}\big( x(\varepsilon), \, \varepsilon\big) - x(\varepsilon) \,=\, 0$$
and as discussed earlier the one parameter family of $\theta-$ periodic solutions $$\phi\big(\,t, \tau, x(\varepsilon), \varepsilon\,\big)$$ of the one parameter family of systems
$$\frac{dx}{dt}\,=\,F(x) \,+\,\varepsilon\, G(x,\,t)$$

For simplicity, set the equilibrium to be $0$ and $A=DF(0)$. So
$$ F(x) = Ax+O(x^2). $$
Thus the DE becomes
$$ x'=Ax+\epsilon f(t)+ O(x^2).$$
Choose the constant $\delta$ to satisfy
$$ \int_0^\theta e^{At}(f(t)-\delta)dt=0.$$
Note that the auxiliary DE is
$$ y' =Ay+\epsilon f(t) $$
which has the solution
$$\begin{eqnarray} y(t)&=&e^{At}y_0+\epsilon\int_0^t e^{A(t-s)}f(s)ds\\
&=&e^{At}y_0+\epsilon\int_0^t e^{As}(f(t-s)-\delta)ds+\epsilon\delta A^{-1}(e^{At}-1)\\
&=&\epsilon g(t)+e^{At}y_0+\epsilon\delta A^{-1}(e^{At}-1)=\epsilon g(t)+o(1) 
\end{eqnarray}$$
where
$$ g(t)=\int_0^t e^{As}(f(t-s)-\delta)ds $$
for small $\epsilon>0$ and big $t$. Now we prove $g$ is periodic. In fact,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
g(\theta+t)&=&\int_0^{\theta+t} e^{As}(f(\theta+t-s)-\delta)ds\\
&=&\int_0^{\theta+t} e^{As}(f(t-s)-\delta)ds\\
&=&\int_0^{t} e^{As}(f(t-s)-\delta)ds+\int_t^{\theta+t} e^{As}(f(t-s)-\delta)ds\\
&=&g(t)+\int_0^{\theta} e^{A(s+t)}(f(s)-\delta)ds=g(t)
\end{eqnarray}$$
So for small $\epsilon$ and big $t$,  $y(t)$ is $\theta$-periodic and hence $x(t)$ is $\theta$-periodic solution in a neighborhood of the equilibrium point.

Thus far you found a periodic solution for the perturbed (to linear) equation. Now you have to show that a periodic solution of the original equation is only a perturbation of the found solution away.
